# How to export a ".wmf" type figure with the frame as a vector but the main figure as a scalar?

Tags: export

I would like to export the following figure in a ".wmf" type, so as to edit it further in PPT. But the exported figure size is too big, about 2 MB. The reason is that there are too many data points in the main figure. So I hope to export the frame  as a vector, while keep the main figure  a scalar (e.g., .jpg  type). In this case, I guess the whole size will be smaller.   Anyone can help me by realizing this purpose? Thank you  all very much.

The code is like this

```
fig1 = ListLinePlot[Table[{x, 200000 Exp[-x*x/10] Abs[Sin[100 x ]]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.01}], PlotStyle -> {Green, Opacity[.8]}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 18], AspectRatio -> .8, FrameTicks -> { {{{0, "0"}, {50000, "50k"}, {100000,    "100k"}, {150000, "150k"}, {200000, "200k"}}, {{0,  ""}, {50000, ""}, {100000, ""}, {150000, ""}, {200000,   ""}}}, {{{-10, "-10"}, {-5, "-5"}, {0, "0"}, {5, "5"}, {10,         "10"}}, {{-10, ""}, {-5, ""}, {0, ""}, {5, ""}, {10, ""}}}}, FrameLabel -> {{"Intensity", None}, {"Delay (mm)", None}},  ImageSize -> {300, 300}];
fig2 = ListLinePlot[   Table[{x, 200000 Exp[-x*x/10]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.01}],    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];
fig3 = Show[fig1, fig2]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["fig.wmf" , fig3]
```

The figure is like this
[image]

Comment: Isn't a bitmap more like a matrix than a scalar?

Comment: aside to the question, never use `jpg` for line-art type graphics.  Look at all the dirty speckles around every sharp line..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer the question (Not to say its a good idea) you can do something like this:

```
raster = Rasterize[Show[fig3, Frame -> False], ImageSize -> {300, 300}];
Graphics[{Inset[raster, {0, 0}, {150, 30}, 20]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {0, 200000}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 18], AspectRatio -> .8, 
     FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "0"}, {50000, "50k"}, {100000, "100k"}, {150000,
      "150k"}, {200000, "200k"}}, {{0, ""}, {50000, ""}, {100000,""},
        {150000, ""}, {200000, ""}}}, {{{-10, "-10"}, {-5, "-5"},
        {0, "0"}, {5, "5"}, {10, "10"}}, {{-10, ""}, {-5, ""},
         {0, ""}, {5, ""}, {10, ""}}}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"Intensity", None}, {"Delay (mm)", None}}, 
       ImageSize -> {300, 300}]
```

Note I manually putzed with the inset scaling to get the raster to align by eye.  I also manually set the plot range after looking at `PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[fig3]` The procedure could probably be automated if you work at it.

[image]

Comment: This answer is just what I need. Thank you so much!

Comment: After I insert this figure to PPT, then add some note(using "ungroup" in PPT), and finally save it as PDF. The size is 22.6kB, and the frame is in vector!!

Answer (score 6):

You have expressed two really BAD ideas: `Export` to outdated WMF format and edit the vector figure in PowerPoint which is not intended for editing vector graphics. With WMF you get low quality and most probably distorted figure, and when you edit it in MS Office you obtain just a junk instead of the original figure.

Do not edit vector figures in MS Office! Add what you need in *Mathematica* or (if the latter is inconvenient) use specialized software for editing vectors like Inkscape, Illustrator or CorelDraw. For this purpose `Export` as PDF because it is the most supported vector format in *Mathematica* AND the most of specialized vector editors can import such files.

If you need to embed vector figure in MS Office file - do not export it in outdated WMF format, export at least as EMF!

Or even better, `Export` as PDF and then convert PDF to EPS Level 2 as described in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/650524/71768): most versions of MS Office can import EPS Level 2 files flawlessly and this format offers much better vector quality than even EMF! Although in some cases (like your example) you can directly `Export` to EPS from *Mathematica* and obtained file is already compatible with MS Office EPS Import Filter because it does not contain PostScript Level 3 instructions (but in more complicated cases you have to go through the PDF -> EPS Level 2 route).

Now about your specific case. When I `Export` your figure as WMF I obtain a 2 Mb file but when I `Export` it as EMF I obtain a 1 Mb file! When I embed the EMF file into a MS Office 2003 Word document I obtain a DOC file of size **30 Kb** (try it yourself!). When I `Export` your figure as EPS I obtain a file of size 117 Kb, and when I embed it into a Word document I obtain a DOC file of size **68 Kb** (try it yourself!). Do you need now any simplification of your figure? You already have everything in the best form!

---

And the last line: as it is correctly pointed out in the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94437/how-to-export-a-wmf-type-figure-with-the-frame-as-a-vector-but-the-main-figur#comment255520_94437), NEVER use lossy JPG format for exporting line-art type graphics. With PNG format you obtain (in the most cases) smaller file size for such type of graphics WITH **lossless quality**.

Comment: I do all of my annotation in powerpoint. Main reason being that I want to tweak things in place and not go back to mathematica to change a font size or something, but also because powerpoint's GUI drawing tools are better IMO.  (I never actually "edit" the underlying graphics though)

Comment: The file size issue is interesting, knowing nothing about the formats it make me think the `WMF` actually has somehow embedded the higher quality `EMF` data for apps that can use it.  (The results look precisely the same on import to powerpoint.)

Comment: I have had serious trouble with EPS import in Word. Most of the time the converter crashes in Word 2003. In Word 2010, the EPS file is inserted, but then the whole of Word crashes. I have stuck to EMF for this reason. (I still provide EPS files for the journals, who want them in this format anyway rather than embedded into the manuscript.)

Comment: @OleksandrR. About compatibility of MS Office EPS Import Filter with different versions of EPS see [this answer of mine](http://superuser.com/a/650524/71768). Sometimes it is necessary to distill EPS from *Mathematica* to another EPS file with PostScript Level 2. In such cases it is preferable to `Export` as PDF, then use `pdftops` as I describe in that answer.

Comment: Thanks. I always use `pdftops` to produce the EPS files but I didn't know that Word can only deal with PostScript level 2. Unfortunately, that the EPS files are in CMYK color space is not negotiable for the journals, so maybe it will still not work, but I will try it anyway. I produce both EPS and EMF from the PDF source anyway, so it is not too much trouble to keep doing that if Word has problems.

Comment: @OleksandrR. What software do you use for conversion of PDF to EMF?

Comment: I use Serif DrawPlus, which can export EMF files. I import the *Mathematica* PDF there, edit it (convert to CMYK, &c.), and save a new PDF and an EMF.

Comment: I find it easier to manually edit the *Mathematica* output in some cases than to persuade *Mathematica* to produce a plot with exactly the characteristics one would want from the beginning. For example, one can use `Ticks -> All` and delete unwanted tick labels, rather than having to reverse-engineer the major and minor tick lengths and draw all ticks manually.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Is Serif DrawPlus able to import *Mathematica*'s PDF flawlessly or some tweaking of fonts, their styles and sizes, line thickness etc. is necessary after importing?

Comment: Generally it is flawless but it does depend on the version. I am having to use version X5 because the newest version X8 cannot import the same PDFs correctly. I have reported this to Serif but so far they have not fixed the bugs.

Comment: I should say that I use this software not quite so much out of considered choice but mainly because my university has a licence agreement that allows me to buy it for only £10. You can download a copy of X5 for free from [here](http://www.serif.com/free-graphic-design-software/) if you're interested. I am not sure how it compares to CorelDraw and Adobe Illustrator since I haven't used those. Nonetheless, I think it is relatively good in terms of its capabilities and ease of use. Compared to PowerPoint the advantage is very clear.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov,  Thank you so much for these good comments. All my oral presentations and poster presentations are made by PowerPoint

Comment: Also, I need to put 9 similar figures together to make the final figure, so, I think it is very useful and easy to process all the figures in PPT.

Comment: "When I embed the EMF file into a MS Office 2003 Word document I obtain a DOC file of size 30 Kb (try it yourself!)."<---- It is smaller, but the frame is no longer a vector.